# How to do pagination in ZendeskAPI ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, zendesk, zendesk-api

If we want to search tickets or list comments of a ticket. We would like the comments to be paginated. Can we achieve through the gem or do we need to use the APIs.

Version used: zendesk_api (1.28.0)

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 0):

Just like the API documentation given in
https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/ticketing/tickets/ticket_comments/#list-comments

Using gem we can do this.

```
ZendeskAPI::Ticket.find($zendesk_client, id: ticket_id).comments(page: page, per_page: per_page, sort_order: sort_order, include_inline_images: true).include(:users)
```